# grouping a linq statement, doesnt seem to group

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I am having a problem trying to group a small linq query.

The query excutes ok however no grouping happens. I assume its due to having 3 different fields I am trying to group.

```
     var data = (from d in All()
                     group d by new { d.CustomerNumber, d.TransactionAmount, d.CustomerName }
                         into g
                         orderby g.Key.CustomerName
                         select new TransactionViewModel
                                    {
                                        CustomerNumber = g.Key.CustomerNumber,
                                        TransactionAmount = g.Sum(s=>s.TransactionAmount),
                                        CustomerName = g.Key.CustomerName
                                    });
```

Ideally I would like to be able to return the grouped data with access to the 3 fields.

What do I need to modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have to do group d by new { d.CustomerNumber, d.TransactionAmount, d.CustomerName }
I just removed TransactionAmount from group by as it is diffrent for each row.

TRy this.

```
(from d in All() group d by new { d.CustomerNumber, d.CustomerName } into g orderby g.Key.CustomerName select new Test { CustomerNumber = g.Key.CustomerNumber, TransactionAmount = g.Sum(s => s.TransactionAmount), CustomerName = g.Key.CustomerName });
```

Comment: Turns out I didnt :) Thanks dotnetstep.